# Audio event listener on mobile doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I can't start playing an audio clip within eventlistener on a mobile device

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Works with PC and Mobile
    $("#play").click(function() {
        var test = new Audio("http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg");
        test.volume = 1;
        test.play();
    });

    // Works with PC only
    $("#play2").click(function() {
        var test = new Audio("http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg");
        test.volume = 1;

        test.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
            test.play(); // or this.play();
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id='play'>Play</button>
<button id='play2'>Play 2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The first button works on PC and Mobile but the second button with the event listener only works on PC. How can I get it to work on mobile too?

The event triggers, I can do alert(123); and it will execute, it just won't play the audio clip.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

You have to call:

```
test.play();
test.pause();
```

And after that you can control the audio element outside of the trigger event.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile devices typically prevent playing of media unless directly called by an event (in this case, `click`). This is to prevent usage of mobile data, but unfortunately limits what you can do with media.